# TSQL: access user data from LDAP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, active-directory, ldap

I have an Active Directory (LDAP) that stores user information. I'm trying to access it using TSQL, but I'm having authentication problems.

The LDAP looks like this (I edited the data):

[image]

The user has the following properties:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to get the info from this user through a TSQL query from SQL Server using OPENROWSET like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject','adsdatasource'; 'domain.com.io\test';'the_sha1_pass',
'SELECT  givenname
    FROM ''LDAP://domain.com.io/ou=Users,
      dc=domain,dc=com,dc=io'' WHERE givenname = ''Test''
      ')
```

But when I execute it I get the following error:

> Server: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 OLE DB provider '
>   ADSDSOObject ' reported an error. The provider indicates that the user
>   did not have the permission to perform the operation.

Now, I don't know if I have to send the authentication of the user I'm trying to query over, or the credentials I use to connect with LDAPAdmin. And if I have to send it, should I send the pass already encrypted or without encryption?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your account have permissions to navigate the OU you are querying?

Comment: @JasonB. I don't know, how can I check that? I'm using LDAPAdmin and I just created the user in that OU and gave it a password

Answer (score 0):

You can change your OPENROWSET query as follows by removing the username and password

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject','adsdatasource',
'SELECT givenname
    FROM ''LDAP://kodyaz.com/DC=kodyaz,DC=com'' WHERE givenname = ''KODYAZ''
      ')
```

Or as an alternative, you can try following query structure

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, 'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://kodyaz.com/DC=kodyaz,DC=com'' WHERE objectCategory=''user'' AND givenname = ''KODYAZ'' ')
```

I added user objectCategory in WHERE clause with givenname parameter in OpenQuery command

Before running above Select statement, you can [add LDAP as linked server in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/active-directory-services-queries-using-openquery.aspx) as shown in referred tutorial

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'ADSI', 'Active Directory Service Interfaces', 'ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource'
```

Comment: If I try the first query, I get a 7321 error. If I try the second, I get the same 7321 error. I think the problem is with authentication, but I don't know what user should go in the ADSI connection, with what password or how to give permission to it from LDAP Admin

Comment: I am a member of my domain and I see that my domain user can query the LDAP server because in linked server I leave the authentication part as current user for a Windows authenticated SQL Server connection and also when I change it to use current user permissions option.